# SQLite - Select by column value count

Tags: sqlite

How do I select by column value count? In SQL query it would be something like this: `select * from band inner join bandsinger on band.id = bandsinger.bandid inner join singer on singer.id = bandsinger.singerid group by band.id having count(singerid=6)>0 and count(singerid=4)>0` if SQLite function `count()` could accept a function as a parameter, but it doesn't.

The point is to select two bands, where two singers with known IDs sing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In this case a query should be: `select * from band inner join bandsinger on band.id = bandsinger.bandid inner join singer on singer.id = bandsinger.singerid where dinger.id = 6 or singer.id=4 group by band.id having count(*)=x` where x is number of given IDs to count.